# Using PyQt5 Objects inside QTabWidget and QScrollArea - QGIS Plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins, pyqt5, user-interface

I'm using PyQt5 and QT Designer to create the user interface for my QGIS plugin. Now I'm learning to use QTabWidget and QScrollArea. What I don't understand is how to use the objects inside tabs or scroll areas. For example in my dialog there are two tabs, inside these there's a scroll area and finally the other objects like labels, lineEdits and buttons. You can see this in the image below. The problem is that if I try to use, as usual in my run method, simple functions like:  `self.dlg.label_2.setText()` or `self.dlg.lineEdit.text()`, I receive this kind of error log: `AttributeError: 'Dialog' object has no attribute 'label_2'`.
How to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it putting lines above mentioned in **add_action** method instead **run** method. To exemplify this, in my test plugin, I added a **QTabWidget** object and, inside first and second tabs, a **QLabel** object; as it can be observed in following image (only for first Tab).

[image]

Afterward, I modified plugin code as follows for changing default text in Qt5 Designer ('TextLabel') for 'test' in first tab and for 'another test' in second tab.

```
.
.
.
    def add_action(
.
.
.
        self.actions.append(action)

        self.dlg.label.setText("test")
        self.dlg.label_2.setText("another test")
.
.
.
        return action
.
.
.
```

After running 'Reload Plugin', I launched it and text inside first and second Tabs were changed as expected. For first tab:

[image]

For second tab:

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Can I see the rest of your plugin? I don't understand what actions is and where I can call the method add_action(). More over I need to trigger it when I click on a button. For example in my run method in this moment I have this: `self.dlg.pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda:self.dlg.label.setText("test")`

Comment: I only added two lines referred to labels. Other lines are acting as references in add,_actions for you find easily its position in this method.

Comment: By the way, I supposed that you are using plugin builder.

Comment: No I'm not, but If this is a "standard" method I could understand how to use it.

Comment: It is easier to work with plugin builder. I don't like the behavior of new versions of this plugin so, I use an older version from this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/ehjvylihfmz28o2/pluginbuilder3.zip?dl=0. It is recommendable to also use experimental Reload plugin. Therefore, any changes you have made to your plugin are updated immediately without leaving QGIS.